# form to check if names match display display alert message saying whether they match or the dont match. if statment used to check the values if same

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onsubmit

Hi guys im trying to make a form which when the user enters two values that are the using an f statement same with an onsubmit event handler. that then shows an alert message if they match. my problem is im not seen onsubmit pop up. or an alert i dont know where im going wrong please help.

```js
function nameCheck(){

    let fname = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
    let fname2= document.querySelector("#fname2").value;

    if (fname1 = = fname2){
       alert("The names match ");

} else if{

    alert("They dont match ");
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title> nameCheck</title>

    <script src="java/nameCheck.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <form action= "">

    Name: <input type="text" id ="fname" name="fname">
     <br><br>
    RenterName: <input type="text" id ="fname2" name="fname2">


    <br>

    <div class = "buttons">
        <input type="submit" onclick()= "nameCheck()" name = "submit"  value="Submit">

        <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </div>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the browser developer tools console in your browser - your code has a syntax error - fix that - also, be aware that you would need to prevent the default form submission process, which isn't reliable if you're using `alert` - different browsers behave differently in this respect (at least, they did the last time I even used `alert`)

Answer (score 1):

Where to begin...

1. there is no `onclick()=""` attribute for elements, it's `onclick=""`
2. you have a space between `= =`
3. there is no `fname1` variable defined
4. you don't have a condition after `else if`
5. if you are using `alert()` just for your own debugging purpose, use `console.log()` instead, it will save you time in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```js
function nameCheck(){

    let fname1 = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
    let fname2= document.querySelector("#fname2").value;

    if (fname1 === fname2){
       alert("The names match ");

} else{

    alert("They dont match ");
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title> nameCheck</title>

    <script src="java/nameCheck.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <form action= "">

    Name: <input type="text" id ="fname" name="fname">
     <br><br>
    RenterName: <input type="text" id ="fname2" name="fname2">


    <br>

    <div class = "buttons">
        


        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit" onclick= "nameCheck()" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </div>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

### Variables

So first, in the `if(fname1 = = fname2)`, and the variable creation, fname and fname1 do not match. Change either one so it matches the other.

### `if()` stuff

This is the equality sign: `===` and you did `= =`. The space has to be a equal sign.

Also, the `else if()` is only when you want multiple if()s. `else` should be used for this program.

### HTML Attribute

The onclick() should be onclick.

Comment: Nitpicking, the input field value will always return string, therefore comparing types with `===` is unnecessary, also you might as well prevent form from submitting by returning `false`

Comment: many thanks for help makes me understand it really well